# SharePoint SPClaimProvider details/usage

Tags: sharepoint, claims-based-identity, claims

I have to implement my own SPClaimProvider for PeoplePicker. There are some methods to override. Problem: I can't figure out some methods/parameters usage. All of these methods are claims specific.

Examples:

- method FillClaimValueTypes. What is claim value type? What doest it mean?
- method FillSearch, parameters hierarchyNodeID, searchTree - what this all is about? How can I use this?

Got ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a chance to check out these articles?
[How to create a claims provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537299.aspx)
[Claims Walkthrough: Writing Claims Providers for SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699494.aspx)

for FillClaimValueTypes - just a list that must match order of FillClaimTypes as well. This is what your provider adds in terms of claims.  The type is a namespace, ie. such as http://mystuff/claims/myspecialclaim - it's a distinguishing identifier.

Check out this to see what methods are called by which process in your farm [Know what process is calling your Claim Provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scicoria/archive/2011/06/06/know-what-process-is-calling-your-spclaimprovider.aspx)

There are other samples out there.  Nancy Brown has a good series:

[Custom Claims Providers: Hierarchical Claims - Part 1, background](http://sharepoint.mindsharpblogs.com/NancyB/archive/2011/03/24/Custom-Claims-Providers%5Bcoln%5D-Hierarchical-Claims-%5Bdash%5D-Part-1,-background.aspx)